# Как настроить eclipse для разработки под Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, eclipse, ide

Нужно разработать приложение под Linux, так как я из веба думал использовать Node + Electron. Но Node оказалось таким днищем, неуправляемый грузовиком со своей асинхронностью и скриптовостью(что собственно логично).

Позже покопался решил идти в С\С++, фрэеймворк выбрал Qt, но так и не смог его настроить под eclipse.
Ни одного примера нет, все устаревшее 2009 года, под новый eclipse не ставиться.
Кто пишет на Qt под Linux-Desktop, просьба помочь короткой инструкцией как начать разработку под Qt в eclipse CDT 2020-06\2020-10, ОС Debian.

Eclipse выбрал потому, что позже придется и под Java код править, если есть другая IDE с таким-же широким охватом языков, буду рад рассмотреть.

Также eclipse бесплатна, ни я сам ни предприятие не смогут позволить полноценное платное IDE.

Comment: у тебя места на диске мало? Почему нельзя установить `IDE` под каждый язык?

Comment: У меня в голове места мало, не хочу к каждой IDE привыкать

Comment: А почему не использовать QT Creator? В принципе, Java там есть. Не знаю, на сколько она там хороша (сам использую только с++), но есть.

Comment: Он не удобный. В eclipse есть С++, JS-PHP, Java все языки что мне нужны

Comment: У JetBrains IDE под кучу языков, CLion для C++, IDEA для Java. Интерфейсы одинаковые, так что разбираться не придётся несколько раз

Comment: Лучше уж сидите дальше на Node + Electron, а Qt имеет тенденцию в сторону Qt Quick, который тот же самый недо веб. У Node хотя бы удобное С++ API. Кроме того, для коммерческого использования Qt очень даже платная.

Comment: мне совесть не позволяет писать на плюсах в иде, написанной на джаве/котлине. Для Java  IDEA хороша (после эклипса конечно), но для плюсов.... я пробовал, больше не хочу.

Comment: @user7860670 Open source на лицензии GPL3. Она разрешает ком. использование

Comment: @kovadim на чем ты пишешь тогда?

Comment: @user7860670, я хотел схитрить и писать интерфейс на веб, а все остальное на Си. Нода не понравилась, я думал раз на ней аж серверные системы видео наблюдения пишут она стала норм. А на самом деле постоянные утечки памяти. Короче для Desktop лучше другой язык.

Comment: @Данил Лицензирование у Qt двойное - коммерческое + опенсорсное, причем второе GPL и LGPLv3. Несмотря на то, что LGPL3 *разрешает* коммерческое использование, совсем не факт, что оно *подходит* для нужд коммерческого использования если оно (коммерческое использование) не подразумевает опенсорсной модели.

Comment: "постоянные утечки памяти" обычно по вине js стороны, особенно если ставить всякий шлак из npm. Ну а на С (вместо С++) писать под ноду - это жесть.

Answer (score 2):

С++ - Visual studio/CLion/QtCreator
Java - intellij idea
PHP - phpStorm
JS - webStorm